# Distinguishing between series and parallel connections in circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, norton

I am not sure how to distinguish if two circuit components are connected in series or parallel.

For example, in the image below, the Rt was calculated by knowing the two resistors are connected in parallel. How do I know if they are connected in parallel?

[image: Image 1]

For the second example, in the image below, the Rt was also calculated knowing the two resistors are connected in parallel, but it seems like a series connection to me.

[image: image 2]

Comment: Is this coursework?  What did the instructor/book say about deciding whether something is parallel or series?  Remember that voltmeters are considered open-circuit (ie, disconnected) and ammeters are consided short-circuit (ie, a wire)

Comment: You don't really understand Thevenin or Norton, yet. That's a big problem. I'm not sure where to start because I'm not sure where you went off the rails, yet.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so I'll explain what I can as an answer.

For the first example, the resistors are in series with the voltage source in the picture(the left picture). However, when the voltage source is converted to a short for calculating Thevenin(the right picture), both ends of the resistors are now sharing the same nodes. To help picture this, you should redraw the picture on the right with the resistor on top located where the voltage source was.

For the second example, the voltage source is converted to a short while the current source is converted to an open. The 2 ohm resistor is ignored because of the open. Rt is given to you as 4 ohms, making it the same circuit as the first example with the exception of the 4A current source being put back into the circuit.

The important thing to look for is whether both ends are sharing the same nodes. Everything that connects in series will only share one node with the parts on either side of it. Everything in parallel shares both nodes.

Put a big round circle on the ends of every part you draw. If there is nothing between one circle and another, it is the same node.

Comment: _"Everything in series shares both nodes"_ - do you mean "everything in **parallel** shares both nodes"?

Comment: Yes I did. Making an edit now. Thank you